# What is the origin of the term 'inverse probability'?

Tags: bayesian, terminology, history

Inverse probability [relates strongly, or is synonymous to](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/492966/what-exactly-does-the-term-inverse-probability-mean), Bayesian probability.

Thomas Bayes applied the idea in ['An Essay towards solving a Problem in the Doctrine of Chances'](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_Essay_towards_solving_a_Problem_in_the_Doctrine_of_Chances) (published in 1763).

Who was the first to use the term 'inverse probability' and why did they call it 'inverse probability' instead of 'reverse probability'?

Comment: See http://jeff560.tripod.com/i.html for some details. On why not reverse, I have no information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading verbatim from [Dale's History of Inverse Probability](https://amzn.to/3miXDGX) he mentions that the first occurrence of the term in English is due to Augustus de Morgan in the 1830's as for instance in his 1834 *Encyclopædia Metropolitana* but he considers that the first "inverse" perspective was to be in [Abraham de Moivre](https://xianblog.wordpress.com/2012/03/07/abraham-de-moivre/)'s 1756 edition of his *Doctrine of Chances*, which contains as an Appendix his 1733 [*Approximatio ad summam terminorum binomii $\overline{a+b}^n$ in seriem expansi*](https://www.worldcat.org/title/approximatio-ad-summam-terminorum-binomii-abn-in-seriem-expansi/oclc/46201788) and uses the term conversely

> ...upon the Supposition of a certain determinate Law according to
> which any Event is to happen, we demonstrate that the Ratio of
> Happenings will continuously approach to that Law, as the Experiments
> or Observations are multiplied: so, **conversely,** if from numberless
> Observations we find the Ratio of the Events to converge to a certain quantity...[1756, p.251]

David Hartley in his 1749 *Observations on Man, His Frame, His Duty and His Expectations* called the above resolution by Mr. de Moivre, a "Solution of the inverse Problem" [p.338-339], mentioning in the same paragraph recovering the probability of " unknown Causes by a sufficient Observation of their Effects"

Dale also points out the use of *a priori* and *a posteriori* [in a Bayesian sense] by Jakob Bernoulli much earlier in *Ars Conjectandi* (posthumously published in 1713).

Richard Price in his 1763 introduction to Bayes' Essay also mentions the "converse problem".